Little help in Rudin' s Functional Analysis 3.22
If $0<p<1$, show that $l^p$ contains a compact set $K$ whose convex hull is unbounded.
Attempt
Consider the sequence $x_n$ defined by $x_n(n) = n^{p-1}$ and $x_n(m) = 0$ if $m \neq n$ and the set $K = \{ 0,x_1,...\}$.
Let us check that $x_n \in l_p, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_n(k)|^p =  n^{(p-1)p} < \infty.  $$
From this, we also have that $x_n \to 0$ in $l_p$, because  $n^{(p-1)p}$ tends to $0$ when $n \to \infty$ as $p-1<0$.
The set $K$ is sequentially compact, that is, every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence, because every subsequence converges to the limit of the sequence $x_n$ which belongs to the set $K$ by definition. Hence, K is compact, because $l_p$ is a metric space (the distance is given by $d(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x(k)-y(k)|^p$).
We prove now that the convex hull is not bounded. I will show that $co(K) \not\subset \mathcal{B}(0,r)$, for any $r>0$, that is, there exists a sequence such that its distance to zero tends to infinity. Let us consider the element $y_n = \frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{n} \in co(K)$. This element verifies
$$d(y_n, 0) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |y_n(k)|^p = \frac{1}{n^p} \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{p(p-1)} $$
but how do I conclude thet when $n \to \infty$ the limit is $\infty$?

Consider a summation over some subsequence of the sequence $\{k^{p(p-1)}\}_{k=1}^n$, for example, starting at $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p(p-1)} \geq \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^n{k^{p(p-1)}}\geq \frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{p(p-1)}=C(p)\cdot n^{p(p-1)+1}
$$
where $C(p)$ is some $p$-dependent constant. Now, let's multiply RHS and LHS of the above by the factor of $\frac{1}{n^p}$:
$$
\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{p(p-1)}\geq C(p) n^{p^2-p+1-p}=C(p) n^{(p-1)^2}
$$
Obviously, since $(p-1)^2>0$ for the given setting of $p$, we have that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\sum_{k=1}^nk^{p(p-1)}\geq C(p)\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{(p-1)^2} = \infty.
$$
Actually, as I can see, this approach is quite the same as that of @Willy Wallace, just the claim about $C(p)$ is derived explicitly.

I see, thank you! Considering this last point, my attempt  is then correct, right?

@Mths for me it seems correct
